# How to disable touch screen in android?

Tags: android, actionscript-3

I am working on a little android app which i use Flash Builder4.5.
what i want to do is when app is loading something,
 
i'd like to disable the touch-screen,or anything similar to that.

Answer (score 3):

Add a transparent, full screen view which is clickable and ignores onClick.

Comment: Thanks, Jarek! I just don't know to add a transparent on flash builder platform, yet! But thanks for your tip, and it did help.